# Demonstration of a property of the adjoint operator in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, linear-algebra

I would like to demonstrate the following property:

> $$(|\psi\rangle\langle\phi|)^{\dagger}=|\phi\rangle\langle\psi|$$

The other properties that concern the adjoint operator I have already been able to demonstrate. I'm missing this one.

Comment: This might help. https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/hermitian-conjugate-of-outer-product.792715/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note
$$
\langle \psi_1 | A \psi_2 \rangle^*  = \langle A \psi_2 |  \psi_1 \rangle = \langle \psi_2 | A^\dagger \psi_1 \rangle
$$
Let $A = |\psi \rangle \langle \phi |$. Then,
$$
\langle \psi_1 | A \psi_2 \rangle^*  = \langle \psi_1 | \psi \rangle^* \langle \phi | \psi_2 \rangle^* = \langle \psi_2| \phi \rangle \langle \psi  | \psi_1 \rangle = \langle \psi_2| ( | \phi \rangle \langle \psi  |  ) | \psi_1 \rangle
$$
Thus, $A^\dagger = | \phi \rangle \langle \psi  |$.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the fact that

$$ \langle \alpha | A \ \beta\rangle = \langle A^\dagger \alpha |\beta\rangle = \overline{\langle\beta|A^\dagger \alpha\rangle}$$

Where the line denotes complex conjugation (as the inner products are complex numbers).  This fits a bit more neatly into the bra-ket notation used to define your operator.